# How to use a terminal pipe to apply action iteratively and save a file to the same folder as the input?

Tags: terminal, pdf, libreoffice

I am trying to recursively find all docx files in a folder (with subfolders) and convert them to pdf using a headless LibreOffice instance. I'd like the output file to be saved in the same folder as the input file. Unfortunately, the output file is always saved in the current directory.

How can I save the output file in the same directory in which the input file was located?

Here are the commands that I have tried:

```
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -print -exec sh -c '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf "{}"' \;
```

I thought it might work by using the `--outdir` option but the files still get saved in the current working directory.

```
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -print -exec sh -c '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir . "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Also, not sure why you add `sh -c`,  should work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `-exec` with `execdir`. Below is taken from `man find`.

```
-execdir utility [argument ...] ;
             The -execdir primary is identical to the -exec primary with the
             exception that utility will be executed from the directory that
             holds the current file.  The filename substituted for the string
             ``{}'' is not qualified.
```

In other words, do the following.

```
find . -type f -name '*.docx' -print -execdir sh -c '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Strangely enough, the files are still saved in my cwd.

Comment: OK, try this instead.